# Blender export to gltf makes red look weird

Tags: export, gltf

I am trying to make a robot head and body in Blender for a WebVR project and I am getting some odd behavior. I have a red material that I am using for both the body and head but when exporting the objects to gltf the head turns out really dark (except for an inset I made). The body looks fine though. What is even more confusing is that this is ONLY an issue with shades of red since my blue model exported just fine for both head and body.

Picture of head in Windows 3D Viewer (looks the same in WebVR):
[image: Picture of head in Windows 3D Viewer (looks the same in WebVR)]

Picture of body (color looks as expected):
[image: Picture of body]

Picture of blue head (same model, just a blue base color for the material):
[image]

Does anyone have any ideas? I already checked and face normals seem to be correct (outwards).

Comment: That's really weird.  Is there any way you can include a Blender project with a sample of the broken color on a mesh?

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of the material setup in blender ?